# Area 51 reputation changes not showing up on reputation tab

Tags: bug, reputation, area-51, reputation-history

I've noticed that whenever I gain or lose reputation on Area 51, it does not show up on the global reputation tab.

Reputation changes are showing up for every other site, but not for Area 51. Is this intentional, or is it a bug?